# Need a way to make this code run faster

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler problem 401](http://projecteuler.net/problem=401). They only way I could find a way to solve it was brute-force. I've been running this code for like 10 mins without any answer. Can anyone help me with ideas improve it.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define ull unsigned long long

using namespace std;

ull sigma2(ull n);
ull SIGMA2(ull n);

int main()
{
    ull ans = SIGMA2(1000000000000000) % 1000000000;

    cout << "Answer: " << ans << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}

ull sigma2(ull n)
{
    ull sum = 0;
    for(ull i = 1; i<=floor(sqrt(n)); i++)
    {
        if(n%i == 0)
        {
            sum += (i*i)+((n/i)*(n/i));
        }
        if(i*i == n)
        {
            sum -= n;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

ull SIGMA2(ull n)
{
    ull sum = 0;
    for(ull i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sum+=sigma2(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: off-topic. post it on code review.

Comment: @ Melika: I don't see how this is off-topic.

Comment: I've been seen people here says that if you are trying to improve your code, SO is not for that. But now I spotted that you said it's not working. ok, wait for the answers. :)

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini : I think the code is operating correctly.  It's just not a very efficient approach.  This is more a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: BTW, depending on your compiler, this could call `sqrt` every iteration: `for(ull i = 1; i<=floor(sqrt(n)); i++)`.  It won't solve the _fundamental_ problem in your code, but it would make the bruteforcing go faster.

Comment: @JoeZ also you can use local variables to half the computation

Comment: FWIW, to have an idea of the numbers involved, 10^15 is 1,000,000 times larger than 1 billion.  So, if just count from 1 to 10^15 at a rate of 1 billion per second, it'll still take you 1 million seconds, which is over 11 days.  And that's just for simple counting, no divides, no function calls, etc.  That's just the `for` loop in your `SIGMA2` function counting by 1, doing nothing else.

Comment: A big improvement in the quality of your question (and your chance of getting good answers) would be if you posted a short description of the problem and the brute force algorithm you used, in addition to, *or instead of*, the link to the problem and the huge block of code. Many people will be unwilling to first go to another site to read the problem, then decipher a page of code without comments, and will simply ignore your question. Restating the problem and your approach in your own words may also help you to come to a better solution.

Comment: @HelloUni You can optimize your code all you want and it's still going to take a long time to run. The problem isn't the level of optimization; you need to better understand the problem. It's going to involve siting down with a pen and paper and working through the algebra to see what kind of mathematical shortcuts you can derive. I haven't had a chance to do this myself, but it probably will involve some fairly straightforward application of basic number theory. Might want to ask a more math oriented question on math.stackexchange.com to improve your understanding.

Comment: This site might be useful: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71550.html.  You'll need to slighlty modify the approach, and it will still take a long time to run using the brute force method above.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some dividers, if a/b=c, and `b` is a divider of `a` then `c` will also be a divider of `a` but `c`might be greater than `floor(sqrt(a))`, for example 3 > floor(sqrt(6)) but divides 6.

Then you should put your floor(sqrt(n)) in a variable and use the variable in the for, otherwise you recalculate it a every operation which is very expensive.

Comment: I tried sigma2 function in the code with argument 6 and it gives the answer 50 which is correct. So that must mean that no divisors are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some straightforward optimizations:

- inline `sigma2`,
- calculate `floor(sqrt(n))` before the loop (but compiler may be doing it anyway, though),
- precalculate squares of all ints from `1` to `n` and then use array lookup instead of multiplication

You will gain more by changing your approach. Think what you are trying to do - summing squares of all divisors of all integers from 1 to n. You grouped divisors by what they divide, but you can regroup terms in this sum. Let's group divisors by their value:

- `1` divides everything so it will appear `n` times in the sum, bringing `1*1*n` total,
- `2` divides evens and will appear `n/2` (integer division!) times, bringing `2*2*(n/2)` total,
- `k` ... will bring `k*k*(n/k)` total.

So we should just add up `k*k*(n/k)` for `k` from `1` to `n`.

Comment: It is a very good idea to group the divisor and multiply them by their frequency. But this is a pure mathematical approach. This will not give you code for sigma2 function I think. So the question is if this assignment shall be solved by mathematics or programming. :)

Comment: Optimizing by rethinking your algorithm is part of programming.

Comment: Can so you an example how I can implement the grouping in the code?

Answer (score 1):

One simple optimization that you can carry out is that there will be many repeated factors in the numbers.

So first estimate in how many numbers would 1 be a factor ( all N numbers ).
In how many numbers would 2 be a factor ( N/2 ).
...
Similarly for others.

Just multiply their squares with their frequency.

**Time complexity shall then straight-away reduce to O(N)**

Comment: Are you going to store the factorizations for all the numbers up to 10^15?  :-)  Where do you buy your hard drives?

Comment: @JoeZ No, you just need to calculate 1^2 * N + 2^2 * N/2 +... No need to store these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the problem.

Bruteforce the way you tried is obviously not a good idea.

You should come up with something better...
Isn't there any method how to use some nice prime factorization method to speed up the computation? Isn't there any recursion pattern? Try to find something...

Answer (score 0):

There are obvious microoptimizations such as ++i rather than i++ or getting floor(sqrt(n)) out of the loop (these are two floating point operations which are really expensive compared to other integer operation in the loop), and calculting n/i only once (use a dummy variable for it and then calculate the square of the dummy).

There are also rather obvious simplifications in the algorithm. For example SIGMA2(i) = SIGMA2(i-1) + sigma2(i). But do not use recursion since you need a really huge number, this would not work and your stack memory would be exhausted. Use loop instead of recursion. There is a huge potential for improvement.

And well, there is a bigger problem - 10^15 has 15 digits. This number squared has 30 digits. There is no way you can store this into unsigned long long, which has I think about 20 digits. So you need to employ somehow the modulo 10^9 (the end of the assignment) and get additional space for your calculations...

And when using brute force, print out the temporary result every milion number for example to give you idea how fast you are approaching to the final result. Waiting 10 minutes blindly is not a good idea.